# Symfony 3: can't overwrite repository

Tags: php, dependency-injection, symfony

I **upgraded** from Symfony **2.7 to 3.0**. It works almost. Only **problem**: I'm not able to overwrite `AppBundle\Entity\MyRepository` in the code below, the file is not even necessary *(I renamed it for testing)* and got skipped by Symfony.

**app/config/services.yml**

```
# old, 2.7 (worked):
myRepositoryService:
  class: AppBundle\Entity\MyRepository
  factory_service: doctrine.orm.entity_manager
  factory_method: getRepository
  arguments: [AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity]

# new, 3.0 (skips the MyRepository):
myRepositoryService:
  class: AppBundle\Entity\MyRepository
  factory: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', 'getRepository']
  arguments: ['AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity']
```

**AppBundle\Entity\MyRepository**

```
class MyRepository extends EntityRepository {
    public function findAll() {
        die("MyRepository->findAll()"); // not executed
    }
}
```

**AppBundle\Controller\MyController.php**

```
$myItems = $this->get('myRepositoryService')->findAll(); // should die but doesn't
```

Did I misconfigure my **services.yml** so that Symfony creates a temporary repository file for the entity instead of using the file I created?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked if `$this->get('myRepositoryService')` is an instance of `AppBundle\Entity\MyRepository`? And have you set `repositoryClass` to this class in entity's mapping?

Comment: @dragoste I forgot to set the `repositoryClass` for this entity. *facepalm* Please post it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I forgot about that a few times too. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code is working for me in Symfony 3.0:

```
some_repository:
    class: AppBundle\Repository\SomeRepository 
    factory: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager', getRepository]
    arguments: [AppBundle:SomeEntity]
```

Please note the different than yours factory service name and that there are no single quotes for factory method and entity name.

Also as I've mentions in my comment, there should be `repositoryClass` set in entity's mapping.

Comment: it's better to quote strings with colon - `arguments: [ 'AppBundle:SomeEntity' ]`